# Can I do 'git svn dcommit' from a SVN git clone which was created with --no-metadata?

Tags: svn, git, clone

I converted a SVN repository to git using

```
git svn clone --stdlayout --authors-file=authors.txt --no-metadata svn://svn.foo.com
```

For some reason, this gave me what looked like a bare repository. There was just a `.git`
directory. In thise cloned repository, I wanted to get a checkout. Since `git checkout` didn't work, I ran

```
git reset --hard
```

Is this the correct way? It seems to work, but sounds scary. I then attempted to run

```
git svn rebase
```

So that the latest changes from the Subversion repository are pulled into my git clone. However, this didn't work. Instead, it yields the message

> Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *believe* this happens because I passed `--no-metadata` to git svn clone. This is what the [git-svn(1)](http://www.au.kernel.org/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) man page says about the 'no metadata' option:

> This gets rid of the git-svn-id: lines at the end of every commit.
>
> If you lose your .git/svn/git-svn/.rev_db file, git svn will not be able to rebuild it and you won't be able to fetch again, either. This is fine for one-shot imports.

I didn't read it like that, but apparently using `--no-metadata` made git svn not generate the `git-svn/.rev_db` file. I do have a `.git/svn` subdirectory, but no `git-svn` below that.

Comment: That's right - the `git-svn-id` lines are essential to `determine upstream SVN information from working tree history`.